# Devise wrong redirection in staging with port 8080

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need create staging env and I set staging in `192.168.1.100:8080/` but when I login the system redirect me to `192.168.1.100/dashborad` instead of `192.168.1.100:8080/dashboard`.

Also if after wrong redirection I enter to `192.168.1.100:8080/dashboard` I can enter wihtout problems. I think I can fix this with `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` but I have problem with all Devise redirection ( sign_in , sign_out)

The question is if exist any Devise configuration to set correct port in all Devise redirection

Comment: I have same problem, have you find solution ?

Comment: I do not remember very well but I think I could not solve this

Comment: Im having the same issue, any idea?

Comment: I thjink I change to subdomain instead port, like `staging.example.com`, not `example.com:8080`